# Data has been deleted automatically when importing JOINed tables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr, solrcloud, dataimporthandler, solr-schema

I have joined 2 mysql tables by JOIN query and have imported data by DIH in SOLR.

But, Half of records deleted automatically. I come to know about this by reading **numDocs** , **maxDocs** & **deletedDocs** values.

I have checked all fields in tables that I have already defined in **data-config.xml** as well as in **schema.xml** files.

What is the problem in this?

Help me in this please.

Comment: deletedDocs : I think it must be a replace of an existing document...      whats the numDocs, maxDocs & deletedDocs count?

Comment: Num Docs:821
Max Doc:1981
Deleted Docs:1160

Comment: This count is remain same when I delete my core and reimport data

Comment: numDocs+DeletedDocs = MaxDocs (821+1160=1981)...numDocs represents the number of searchable documents in the index (and will be larger than the number of XML files since some files contained more than one ). maxDoc may be larger as the maxDoc count includes logically deleted documents that have not yet been removed from the index. if you reindex/repost numDocs will never increase, because the new documents will constantly be replacing the old...try optimizing the index, it might remove the logically deleted documents/indexs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a  replace of an existing document

```
numDocs+DeletedDocs = MaxDocs 
 (821+1160=1981)
```

numDocs represents the number of searchable documents in the index 
maxDoc may be larger as the numDoc count as it includes logically deleted documents that have not yet been removed from the index.

If you reindex/repost numDocs will never increase, because the new documents will constantly be replacing the old...try optimizing the index, it might remove the logically deleted documents/indexs.

The Unique Key Field

```
<uniqueKey></uniqueKey>
```

The `<uniqueKey>` declaration can be used to inform Solr that there is a field in your index which should be unique for all documents. If a document is added that contains the same value for this field as an existing document, the old document will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this. But, my question is why its been deleted? My mysql data is 1981 but why it only allows 821 docs? and why its deleted ?

Comment: whats the uniqueKey in your schema.xml? and how many entries your mysql database has for that? I mean is the primary key in the mysql as well?

Comment: Main **User** table has **ID** unique key. Another table has same unique key but **user.id=tal.userid**

Comment: Today I have joined 3 tables **user**, **country** & **cities**. **User** table has uniqueKey **ID**, **Country** table has uniqueKey **country_id** & **Cities** table has uniqueKey **city_id** and its joined perfectly and by importing that data It had not deleted any data. So i come to know that all joined tables have different **uniqueKey** that works perfectly. But in my second **JOIN**, I have same uniqueKey in 2 different tables and It have remains same problem that deletes my docs. So how do i define 2 uniqieKeys for 2 different tables in **Schema.xml** file ??

Comment: whats the <uniqueKey></uniqueKey> in defined in your schema.xml?

Comment: when joining 2 tables **User -> id**, **Country -> country_id**, **Cities -> city_id** there is no problem. But joining these **User -> id**, **User_works -> id** 2 tables then it does problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78497/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-mayur-champaneria).